# How to add multiple shapefile into a single table in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, table

How to add multiple same geometry shapefile (such as polygons) into a single table in PostGIS?

For example:
test_1 is a shapefile (polygon)
test_2 is a shapefile (polygon)
test_3 is a shapefile (polygon)

All of them should transfer into a test table.

How?

Comment: Do they have exactly the same set of columns?

Comment: not all the columns are the same. But yes, main columns like id, name, etc, etc are the same.

Comment: I would try [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) with append flag. But I havent tried it with different columns

Comment: The thing is, I have tried it but it gave the error of the same data type or also data is already there.
How did you do with Ogr2ogr? could you please explain that?